# What is the best layout I should use to meet my requirements in Android App Development about regional advertisements and overlapping Views

Tags: java, android

I am working on various type of ads that can be implemented to a pre existing streaming app.

The content provider will chose what kind if ads they want to be displayed and it should show on the screen.

I was thinking about making different Image/Text Views for each type of ad and making them overlap and only displaying the ones that are currently being scheduled and and visibility for the ones not currently scheduled is GONE.

Different type of ads are Banner Ads, L - Band Ads (2 images form a l-shaped ad in the bottom left corner of the screen), Scrolling Text Ads etc.

What is the best layout I can use to implement this (some view position are relative to each other like l band other depend on parent like banner is aligned to bottom of the screen)?

Comment: Welcome to SO , Please provide some code or at least you attempt to solve your issue .

Answer (score -1):

If you are keeping other layouts as GONE then using Linear Layout will be good to use. You will be displaying only one layout at a time so there is no need for any special Layout.